# Why does this print if and else?

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm working on a blackjack game for my python class, and I'm having a hard time with my if, if, else statement when I ask the player if they want to hit. Its such a small and stupid thing, but I can't for the life of me understand why this happens.

```
def playerDraw():
    getinput = True

    while getinput == True:

        print("do you want another card?")
        temp = input("Type y for yes, n for No:       ")


        if temp == 'y' or temp == 'Y':
            playerTurn = False
            getinput = False
            print("yes")


        if temp == 'n' or temp == 'N':
            playerTurn = False
            getinput = False
            print("no")
        else:
            print("try again")
```

I ask the user if they would like to draw another card, or to end their turn. When the user inputs "yes" it prints the new card and then it also prints "try again", and when the user inputs "no", it only prints ends the turn.
Why in the first if statement, does it print the else code body as well?

Comment: Please put the actual text of your code here in Stack Overflow. That way it's more accessible and it will remain here when the external link has broken.

Comment: It inspects the first condition and prints `yes` according to its result, but then it goes to the other `if-statement` and find the condition false, so it prints the `else` part which is `try again`.

Comment: It is actually very easy. If `temp` is "y" then it is not "n". So when it is checked wether it is "n", it fails this test and the statement under "else" are executed... You can solve this by changing `if temp == 'n'` to `elif temp...`.

Comment: Now is a very good time to learn how to do [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). And learn about `elif` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code the second `if` (for 'n' or 'N') is entered no matter what happen in the first `if`. You need to use `elif` as in the following:

```
def playerDraw():
    getinput = True

    while getinput == True:

        print("do you want another card?")
        temp = input("Type y for yes, n for No:       ")

        if temp == 'y' or temp == 'Y':
            playerTurn = False
            getinput = False
            print("yes")

        elif temp == 'n' or temp == 'N':
            playerTurn = False
            getinput = False
            print("no")
        else:
            print("try again")
```